# Java - I want to get the date value of the calendar java

Tags: java, android, calendar

[image]

Enter the title with edittext and press the calendar button to display the start and end dates in the textview, respectively. It's perfect up to here.

However, I try to store data on db using this, but I don't think I can store the date. I thought we could put the data shown in StartLabel into the variable. Is this wrong?

I want to save the start date 2022-01-28 in startdate.
Likewise, I want to save the end date in enddate.
But it's not saved. Help me.....

```
public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText event_title;
    private TextView start_date_text;
    private ImageView start_date_btn;

    private TextView end_date_text;
    private ImageView end_date_btn;
    private Button event_save_btn;

    private String startdate, enddate;

    Calendar sCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar eCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);

        start_date_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_date_text);
        end_date_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.end_date_text);

        event_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        start_date_btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.start_date_btn);
        end_date_btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.end_date_btn);
        event_save_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.event_save_btn);

        mTextViewResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result_text);
        mTextViewResult.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        //show start_date
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDatePicker1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                sCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                sCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                sCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                startLabel();
            }
        };

        //show end_date 
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDatePicker2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                eCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                eCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                eCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                endLabel();
            }
        };

        //click start calendar btn
        start_date_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DatePickerDialog(EventActivity.this,
                        myDatePicker1,
                        sCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        sCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        sCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });

        //click end calendar btn
        end_date_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DatePickerDialog(EventActivity.this,
                        myDatePicker2,
                        eCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        eCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        eCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });

   ..........

    }


    private void startLabel() {
        String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";    //2018/11/28
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.English);

        TextView start_date_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_date_text);
        start_date_text.setText(sdf.format(sCalendar.getTime()));

        startdate = start_date_text.toString(); // for save startdate
    }

    private void endLabel() {
        String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";// 2018/11/28
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.English);

        TextView end_date_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.end_date_text);
        end_date_text.setText(sdf.format(eCalendar.getTime()));

        enddate = end_date_text.toString(); // for save enddate

    }

................
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Can you try printing the values of startdate and enddate?

Comment: FYI: The terrible legacy classes such as `Calendar` were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in Java 8 and later. These classes are built into Android 26+. For earlier Android, the latest tooling makes most of their functionality via "API desugaring".

Comment: @BasilBourque unfortunately many of us have to support a legacy code base full of Calendar class instances everywhere, but yeah you're right.

Comment: btw your code is a mess, how are you trying to save the `end_date_text.toString()` object as `String` in a variable ? Instead you want the value of `EditText` like this `end_date_text.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
private void startLabel() {
    String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";    //2018/11/28
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.English);

    TextView start_date_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_date_text);
    start_date_text.setText(sdf.format(sCalendar.getTime()));

    startdate = start_date_text.toString(); // for save startdate
}
```

Try doing it like this:

```
private void startLabel() {
    String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";    //2018/11/28
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.English);

    startdate = sdf.format(sCalendar.getTime()); // for save startdate

    TextView start_date_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_date_text);
    start_date_text.setText(startdate); 
}
```

You can do the same for the *endLabel()*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it:

````
    startdate = start_date_text.getText.toString(); // for save startdate ```
````

also the same for enddate